# Get Shipping Adress City State From Checkout page In Custom Module Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping

How to get city state value from onepage checkout in Magento 2 in custom module
i had use below code for Magento 1.X but cant do it for magento 2.x
have any suggestion ? how can i get these values ?

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getCity();

Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getRegionId();
```

Comment: After order placed you want to retrieve right?

Comment: No when user is at checkout page.

Comment: i am not able to solve that one.
$this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getCity();
this is not working for non login or guest users

Answer (score 5):

We can do the same:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
 */
protected $_checkoutSession;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
)
{
    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;

}
```

And then, we can get:

```
 $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getCity();
 $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getRegionId();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But by using this i cant get address if user is not logged in or have no account (Guest).

Comment: Basically, at the first time, the guest has no account and address. They will be available when we set them on checkout page. You tried to get them after putting the address info?

Comment: Yes. At checkout page all form fields are blank but when i fill up all address fields (city, state, zipcode), under Shipping Methods displays "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time"

Comment: Please, check the available shipping methods for your address - city, state, country...etc.

Comment: I am providing "Chicago IL 60603" for these fields. It returning quotes at cart shipping estimates but not at checkout.

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem. In Admin, you should enable Free shipping Method and then check again.

Comment: you have to trigger "estimate-shipping-methods" after check city